# How can I combine two conditions in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have two Perl one liners:

```
perl  -pe "s/\b$a\b/$b/g if m/param1 /"  test
```

and

```
perl  -pe "s/\b$a\b/$b/g unless /^#/" test
```

How can I combine the`if m/somthing/` and the `unless /something/`, like:

```
[root@localhost tmp]#  perl  -pe "s/\b$a\b/$b/g if m/param1/ unless /^#/"  test
syntax error at -e line 1, near "m/param1/ unless"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an unrelated note, you may want to add the [`\Q` and `\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences) escape sequences around `$a` in your regex:

```
perl  -pe "s/\b\Q$a\E\b/$b/g if m/param1 /"  test
```

They escape any characters that are special to regexes.  If you intend for `$a` to hold a regex you should probably move the word boundary assertions (`\b`) into it.

No matter what you choose to do, you will need to be careful with values in `$a` and `$b`.  For instance:

```
a="/"
b="slash"
perl  -pe "s/\b\Q$a\E\b/$b/g if m/param1 /"  test
```

will cause a syntax error.  One solution to this is to not use environment variables to replace code.  Perl allows you access to the environment through the [`%ENV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25ENV) hash:

```
perl -pe 's/\b\Q$ENV{a}\E\b/$ENV{b}/g if m/param1 /' test
```

Notice the use of single ticks to avoid treating `$ENV` as a shell variable.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

```
perl  -pe "s/\b$a\b/$b/g if m/param1/ && ! /^#/"  test
```

does it.

Answer (score 2):

`unless` is the same as `if not`. Judging by the way you've written the statement, I'm guessing you mean the following:

```
 perl  -pe "s/\b$a\b/$b/g if m/param1/ and not /^#/"  test
```

(Although, you might have meant `or` instead of `and`?)

Comment: Also note that its better to use && instead of 'and'. 'and' has a much lower priority than &&